# How to retrieve share-able links using dropbox core-api with android

Tags: android, dropbox, core-api

Recently I have been trying to fetch shareable links to files within my dropbox account from an app I'm creating. The authentication works. How would I go about getting the shareable links using the core-api.

Answer (score 0):

Just call [`share`](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/index.html).

(Adding more text to appease Stack Overflow.)